# Second item in listview doesn't render the first time properly

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

So I have this problem that I have a listview and when I add the first item it renders, but the second one doesn't render but the panel the listview is on grows as if it did. Afterwards if a third item is added both the second and the third render. After that, each new item added renders instantly. This problem is only with the second item.

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="DownloadList" Background="WhiteSmoke" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="DownloadList_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Width="649" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.View>                  
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FormattedSize}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Speed" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FormattedSpeed}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="170" Header="Progress">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <ProgressBar Name ="dlPrgrs" Height ="20" Width="150" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding FormattedProgress}" Foreground="{Binding ForColor}"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=dlPrgrs, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="65" Header="Time Left" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FormattedTime}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="Peers" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Peers}"/>
         </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

behind code

list creation and binding:

```
List<FileDownload> wpfDownloads = new List<FileDownload>();
DownloadList.ItemsSource = wpfDownloads;
```

adding new item:

```
wpfDownloads.Add(download);
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ObservableCollection<FileDownload>` instead of `List<FileDownload>`.
Cause `ObservableCollection<T>` has implemented `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface.

[As MSDN says:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> `INotifyCollectionChanged` notifies listeners of dynamic changes, such
>   as when an item is added and removed or the whole list is cleared.

**Simple advice about your UI:**

I suggest you to create you resizable XAML, not static. I mean it is bad:

```
<Grid>        
   <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10">
       ...The code omitted for the brevity...
   </ListView>
   <Button Margin="50" Name="btn_add" Click="btn_add_Click" Content="Add new item"/>
</Grid>
```

However, it is better and this UI(XAML) is resizable:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="5*">
      </RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left">
       ...The code omitted for the brevity...
    </ListView>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="btn_add" Click="btn_add_Click" Content="Add new item"/>
</Grid>
```