# Bindings on Datagrids in code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I'm working on a cookbook for myself, written in WPF/C#.
Additionally I'm new to Data Bindings.

My Problem is, I want to generate a Datagrid in a TabItem on runtime in code behind, including Bindings. I can't set a Datagrid at XAML because I want to create all TabItems dynamically.

Following Code so far:

XAML:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="2" Rows="1">
<TabControl Name="TabControl" TabStripPlacement="Left"/>
  <TabItem Header= "first dish" Name = "firstdish"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

XAML.cs for generation:

```
//New Grid
        var Grid = new DataGrid();

        //Start Test list creation with three items
        var TestList = new List<Receipt>();

        //Set binding
        Grid.ItemsSource = TestList;

        var Rec = new Receipt();
        Rec.Creator = "DaJohn1";
        Rec.ID = 1;
        Rec.Title = "TestReceipt1";

        var Rec2 = new Receipt();
        Rec2.Creator = "DaJohn2";
        Rec2.ID = 2;
        Rec2.Title = "TestReceipt2";

        var Rec3 = new Receipt();
        Rec3.Creator = "DaJohn3";
        Rec3.ID = 3;
        Rec3.Title = "TestReceipt3";

        TestList.Add(Rec);
        TestList.Add(Rec2);
        TestList.Add(Rec3);
        //End Test list creation

        //Add Column
        var SingleColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
        Grid.Columns.Add(SingleColumn);
        SingleColumn.Binding = new Binding("Creator");
        SingleColumn.Header = "Creator";

        //Add Column
        var SingleColumn2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        Grid.Columns.Add(SingleColumn2);
        SingleColumn2.Binding = new Binding("Title");
        SingleColumn2.Header = "Title";

        //Set tabitem content to datagrid
        firstdish.Content = Grid;
```

All I'm getting is an datagrid with four rows (looks like the count of Items is right), which are all empty, no data to be seen.
I'm staring at this since last Weeks Monday and can't find an answer anywhere.

Thanks for any ideas and solutions.

Comment: Is the Creator variable in the Receipt class public? in order for UI to access it it needs to look like this: 
public string Creator {get;set;}

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
var TestList = new List<Receipt>();
```

to

```
var TestList = new ObservableCollection<Receipt>();
```

as it automatically notifies UI about changes.
I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375878/second-item-in-listview-doesnt-render-the-first-time-properly) with items not rendering so this may be it.

Comment: This didn't make any change, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your code and checked some of the things you do: The main error is that in your xaml code you created the Tab Control and then Put the TabItem outside it, Tabitem must be inside the control for it to work correctly. so First error is:

```
<TabControl Name="TabControl" TabStripPlacement="Left">
<TabItem Header="First dish" Name = "firstdish" />
</TbControl>
```

Other things you need to do before going on in my opinion are:

- Assign your window or other UI element itself as datacontext
- Verify that your Receipt class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged event that has to be raised by all its properties, or implement your properties as DependencyProperties (even if the latter is not necessary)
- Transform your datasource TestList in an ObservableCollection
- Create TestList as a class property not a local variable so that it is into the datacontext

I've made a small sample using the above indication and your code to let you see better how that works. You can download the zip here:
[TestClassDataGrid.zip](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6E87BE4937E1E5A7!19655&authkey=!AIwaKqoI09jspP0&ithint=file%2Czip)

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work for you,

XAML:

```
 <TabControl Name="TabControl" TabStripPlacement="Left">
       <TabItem Header= "first dish" Name = "firstdish"/>
  </TabControl>
```

.cs file

```
public Window()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var Grid = new DataGrid();

            //Start Test list creation with three items
            var TestList = new List<Receipt>();

            //Set binding
            Grid.ItemsSource = TestList;

            var Rec = new Receipt();
            Rec.Creator = "DaJohn1";
            Rec.ID = 1;
            Rec.Title = "TestReceipt1";

            var Rec2 = new Receipt();
            Rec2.Creator = "DaJohn2";
            Rec2.ID = 2;
            Rec2.Title = "TestReceipt2";

            var Rec3 = new Receipt();
            Rec3.Creator = "DaJohn3";
            Rec3.ID = 3;
            Rec3.Title = "TestReceipt3";

            TestList.Add(Rec);
            TestList.Add(Rec2);
            TestList.Add(Rec3);
            //End Test list creation

            //Add Column
            var SingleColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
            Grid.Columns.Add(SingleColumn);
            SingleColumn.Binding = new Binding("Creator");
            SingleColumn.Header = "Creator";

            //Add Column
            var SingleColumn2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
            Grid.Columns.Add(SingleColumn2);
            SingleColumn2.Binding = new Binding("Title");
            SingleColumn2.Header = "Title";

            //Set tabitem content to datagrid

            Grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            firstdish.Content = Grid;
        }
```